# Power BI: Archive with Constant Start Date for Incremental Refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am setting up a basic Power BI incremental refresh: it will incrementally refresh the last two months of data, and I want it to archive up to the start of the fiscal year, in this case 30 Jan 2017. The issue with this is that, to my understanding, the archive option will only allow you to select a certain "moving range" of data. For example, I can archive the last five years of data, but this range will constantly be moving since it is relative to the current date. I want the start date of the archived data to remain constant, so we can maintain the full fiscal year's worth of data even after an incremental refresh.

I haven't done any tests yet, but I am thinking one possibility would be to have it archive the entire range of data (e.g. 999 years), and then put a custom date filter on the dataset with the start date being 30 Jan 2017 and the end date being the RangeEnd parameter. I'm not sure if this would work, and it would feel a bit hacky even if it did.

In short, is there a way to have the incremental refresh archive with a set start date in mind (e.g. continue to archive data 2017 and onwards), as opposed to the relative range of "x years"?